# Editing movies with FFMPEG in command line

Tags: ffmpeg, editing

Is there any crazy guy out there who has tried to mount an entire movie (short or not) using the army knife *ffmpeg* command line tool?

Comment: Certainly not anyone sane. Do you plan to try?

Comment: If nobody do it I think about it ;-)

Comment: There is currently no true operating free open source editing software, this would be a good starting point no?

Comment: https://www.shotcut.org/

Comment: @MartinDelille https://kdenlive.org/ also ...

Comment: Also, [MLT Multimedia Framework](https://mltframework.org/) which is used by several desktop video editors and can be used via command line with `melt`.

Comment: Yes you're right, there is. I also hear about one from the team of VLC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While travelling with my 10-year-old Linux laptop I produced an application [video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ogq0zegq9nimbez/I%20Have%20Something%20in%20My%20Moustache.mp4?dl=0) for an acrobatics teacher training.  Nothing fancy, but it turned out decent.  I'm not sure if this qualifies as a "movie" since it's just a series of unrelated clips accompanied by music. The video is about 10 minutes long.  It's also up on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iUz5AjcUhrM) but I think not playable in some countries due to use of copyrighted music.

I was working on another one, an acroyoga flow performance shot on a couple of phones, but there [didn't seem to be a way](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/18518/how-to-produce-a-zoom-animation-of-a-video-source-with-ffmpeg) to get `ffmpeg` to do a Ken Burns zoom over multiple frames of video without a weird stuttery effect.  So I decided to wait until I got home to finish that one in FCP.

I found it was a pretty straightforward approach.  I like that the parameters are all explicitly stated and you don't have to go digging into settings in the hope that you might figure out how to, for example, replicate the scaling that you used on a particular clip.  Perhaps that speaks to my lack of experience with video editing.  Also if you're not a relatively advanced command line user it would be more complicated for you.  I probably spent most of my time Googling how to perform particular manipulations with `ffmpeg`. I think the whole editing process took about the equivalent of a work day.

Comment: Nice sound track btw